# 1 hour transfer in AMS from Schengen to Non-Schengen destination

Tags: transit, airport-transfer, short-connections, ams

I'm flying from Aalborg Airport (AAL) in Denmark via Amsterdam Schiphol to Tokyo Narita, the estimated transit time is 55 minutes, will this be enough time to make my transfer?

Both flights are with KLM and booked on the same ticket.
This is also my first time flying post-pandemic and my first time flying outside Schengen, as well as my first time not flying direct.

I'd appreciate if anyone has any tips to navigating AMS, I read that there's a Schengen wing and a non-Schengen wing, but how will that affect me, arriving from a Schengen country, will I need to pass through any checks to enter the non-Schengen wing?

Comment: Could be tight. [KLM’s website](https://www.klm.co.uk/information/airport/transfers) says *“The minimum required transfer time at Amsterdam Airport Schiphol is usually around 50 minutes”*

Comment: Not writing an answer as I don't have enough first hand experience here. But a single ticket means they know it is feasible. Definitely if you arrive at a terminal gate (walk in). - this will likely be B or C gates. In that case you'll arrive in the Schengen area and then can transfer to the non-Schengen area through dedicated exit points. You'll end up in the general post-security departure area and then have to go to E or F gates I guess. Schiphl is a large but very compact airport - definitely doable. Your luggage should be checked through and will make it easily. They're efficient there.

Comment: Yes, there will be passport checks upon leaving the Schengen area, but you shouldn't need to go pass through security again. Now my last and only experience in transiting AMS was seven years ago, and I don't know if the "short connection lines" at passport control are still there, so I'll leave it to someone who has more (and more recent) experience to write an answer.

Comment: I would not do such flight. It is feasible, but I lost an intercontinental flight (also to Asia) because of the delay. And in such cases you do not have many options, but to stay an other day (hoping there is a seat on next flight). KLM cares about you, but you lose one day. -- If you already booked, ask if you can get an early flight, or go in airport early and if you see some delay contact KLM staff as soon as possible (it cost less to them to put you in a different flight of a different company compared the missed flight in AMS).

Answer (score 4):

Feasible? - Yes. Comfortable? - Not really.

Have been flying between non-Schengen countries (Romania) and Schengen countries (Finland) via Amsterdam three times in the last two years with 50 minute transfer time. There hasn't been another security check but a passport check. When you are on a single ticket and your first plane is late, KLM will send you a text message which you can show to skip some queues.

However, it is not very comfortable. Schiphol is rather huge. Walking from gate to gate alone takes plenty of time. You will *not* have time to have a coffee or do any shopping. Just walk to the departing gate as quickly as possible.